# Setting up express routing, API call returns 404 not found

Tags: javascript, api, express, routes

I'm having difficulty understanding how to set up my Express routing with `app.use` and `router`. The way I understand from documentation is that you can set up a router and then pass it to a route with `app.use()` and have that router handle all routing to that route. Could someone help me understand whats work with my logic? Any help much appreciated.

#### Routing

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    PlayingGame = mongoose.model('PlayingGame'),
    FinishedGame = mongoose.model('FinishedGame');


var waiting_user = null;

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/game', router);
};

router.get('/game/waiting', function(req, res, next) {
    if (waiting_user !== null) {
        console.log('lets put you two in game');
    } else {
        console.log('you need to wait for another player');
    }
});
```

#### Client Call

```
var play = () => {
    var username = username_input.val();

    if (isUsernameValid(username)) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/game/waiting',
                type: 'GET',
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });
    } else {
        alert('Put in a valid username');
    }
};
```

Comment: The paths given to `app.use()` and `router.get()` will be combined (`'/game' + '/game/waiting'`). So, you've defined the route `GET /game/game/waiting`.

Comment: hey that worked. if you post an answer I can accept

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you write '/game' twice and that's mean your route become 'baseurl:3000/game/game/waiting'.

If you wan't to change from route, update this :

```
// remove this : router.get('/game/waiting', function(req, res, next) {
router.get('/waiting', function(req, res, next) {
    if (waiting_user !== null) {
        console.log('lets put you two in game');
    } else {
        console.log('you need to wait for another player');
    }
})
```

But if you want to change on client call, you can update this :

```
var play = () => {
    var username = username_input.val();

    if (isUsernameValid(username)) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/game/game/waiting',  /* remove this : '/game/waiting', */
                type: 'GET',
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });
    } else {
        alert('Put in a valid username');
    }
};
```